# Best poker coaching program

Tags: texas-hold-em

What do you think is the best poker coaching program out there? I am looking for a structured program and for this reason will not use pokerstrategy 2+2 or other sites that offer separate lessons. So far im choosing between BPC and upswing. Have you used those? what are your thoughts? have you used others?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a shopping list question. Any answer offered while it might be helpful to you today will not likely be valid or good information for future visitors to the site. Such is the nature of questions asking for best books, best software etc. on most SE sites.